# What is the best way of storing string data

Tags: c#, string

I am keep hearing that many string containers so i am confused. What are those and which is the best one

- string builder
- arraylist
- list<>

I know it may depend how big your string is and how much modification exists but generally which one of them a programmer prefer?

Comment: The best way to store string data is in a string.

Comment: "Best one" needs additional clarification: "Best performance", "Best memory usage", "Best xyz", …

Comment: Programmers generally prefer [this container](https://www.google.co.in/search?ei=dpInWq6vPMny8AXjuqUQ&q=best+way+of+storing+string+data+c%23&oq=best+way+of+storing+string+data+c%23&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6149.6149.0.7064.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.t1uTRSCjkLA)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to **store** string data is in a string.
That's why it's there for.

If you want to **manipulate** a string that's a different story - since strings are immutable, any change you need to make will create a new string, meaning new memory allocation and sometimes extra time.

When concatenating strings, I think I remember the magic number is about 5 or 6 - so anything less than 6 parts is better to concatenate using the string concatenation operator (`+`), and anything more it's better to use a `StringBuilder`. Do not use `string.Format` to concatenate strings, it has a massive overhead and very poor performance compared to the other two options I've mentioned.